# Remove some data as part of groupBy

Tags: scala

This code :

```
import scala.collection.immutable.Set;

object Update extends App {

  val ss: List[Set[(String, String)]] = List(Set(
    ("sentance1", "url1"),
    ("sentance2", "url1"),
    ("sentance3", "url2")
  ));

  val linesWithUrl: List[Map[String, Set[(String, String)]]] = ss.map(m => m.groupBy(_._2))

  linesWithUrl.foreach(println)
}
```

returns :

```
  Map(url1 -> Set((sentance1,url1), (sentance2,url1)), url2 -> Set((sentance3,url2)))
```

I want to return just the sentences as values within the map :

```
  Map(url1 -> Set((sentance1), (sentance2)), url2 -> Set((sentance3)))
```

Method I'm considering is to iterate over linesWithUrl and create a map with just the required values, but can the expected data structure be created in an alternative way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't think of anything alternative. I believe what you proposed - mapping over it afterwards - is the correct way to do it:

```
ss.map(m => m.groupBy(_._2).mapValues(_.map(_._1)))
```

I'm not saying this as some kind of rule, but personally I usually strive for solutions that are simplest and most obvious unless there is a performance issue. Doing it any other way would probably make it more difficult for anyone who's trying to understand your code afterwards.

EDIT: As a style-related side note, I noticed now that you used `m => m.groupBy`. If that's how you prefer, also change my `_.map` to something like `s => s.map` (consistency is a great thing :)). It's probably unnecessary for tuples though.